# Manage thread count with respect to available memory in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, memory-management

How to manage thread count with respect to available memory in Java.
That means, I want to control the count of running threads, by coding, with respect to memory available in the server.
Any types of suggestion, tips, tutorial, lib is welcome.

Comment: Create a threadpool based on your memory. you can use Executorservice to create threadpool and manage threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use executorService. In [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) it is actually recommended to set the thread count based on the number of processors. I think the formula was thread count = number of processors + one, but I may remember wrong...

Comment: Thanks Kristjan!.. its really helpful! up from me!